# Betfair Python API

Tags: python, api, betfair

My answer is quite specific to the Betfair API however I would like to know how to use more APIs in general. I'm quite new to this sort of thing so don't really know how it works. I've just downloaded this package: https://github.com/jmcarp/betfair.py
My question is, how am I supposed to know the functions that come associated with it? How am I supposed to be able to know how to pull the data that I want from any given website without having any resource describing the functionality of the API?

Comment: In general, refer to the documentation (reference documentation, tutorial, examples...) to learn how to use a new API. If the library you are using is undocumented, you should seriously consider switching to a documented one. If you still want to use it, then you will need to do the research yourself: study the source code, google usage examples, ask questions on relevant forums, etc.

Comment: I was kind of afraid that that was going to be the answer. Was really just looking for an easy solution but I guess that is just me being lazy! Thanks for answering though

Comment: Reverse engineer existing client.

Comment: completely valid question for new bee, thats why industry is coming up with few standard to document the API as the eco system is growing since last few years. Kindly look at http://raml.org/ and http://swagger.io/ they suggest spec and tool to generate api documentation and it is being widly adopted as well.

Answer (score 0):

These library is only a binding (with several errors) to Betfair APIs.

You can find documentation about this API, and therefore about this library, in [Developer's web](https://api.developer.betfair.com/).

If you're interested in how to use Betfair APIs in Python you can take a look at [Betfair's code samples](https://github.com/betfair/API-NG-sample-code/tree/master/python).

Comment: I have looked at a lot of different code samples and I've figured out how to do a fair amount (I asked this question a while back and have since tried to find other methods to connect). There is still a lot of stumbling blocks that I encounter though and I'm not sure about how to get past them as there is nobody to really ask and the documentation really isn't helpful enough...

Comment: In the project GitHub's page you can find how to make a connection with API servers and a little example of getting markets showing how to apply filters for actions.

The rest of the library just mimetizes the Betfair APIs (same names, same types of data). In Developers' page you can find support for this.

Also you can take a look at better implementations in other languages (as R) to learn about how to schedule different processes in Betfair.